# Javascript Changing Lower case to an array after adding more item to the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

> I try to make all the trees after sorting to lowercase but For some reason, I cannot make the lower case to the listTree() work!
> I know that to lowercase() need to be pasted in a function in order for it to work with the array. But I am not sure how to add to the listTrees() function. Do we need to use if-else statement?

```
const trees = ['oak', 'Pine', 'aspen', 'Bald Cypress']

const errorElement = document.querySelector('#error')
const displayResults = document.querySelector('#displayResults')



const listTrees = () => {
    let treeList = ''
    trees.forEach(tree => {
        treeList += `${tree} <br>`
    })
    displayResults.innerHTML = `${treeList} <span>${trees.length} elements long </span>`

}

listTrees()


document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
    if (trees.length > 0) {
        trees.lowercase()
        listTrees()
    }
    else {
        errorElement.textContent = 'Dude, I cannot remove the last tree cause there are NO TREES!'
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toLowerCase()` is only used with strings here you are using `toLowerCase()` with array. If you want all array items to be in lowercase you need to transform each array items like that:

```
document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
if (trees.length > 0) {
    trees.map((el, i) => {
       trees[i] = el.toLowerCase()
    });
    listTrees()
}
else {
    errorElement.textContent = 'Dude, I cannot remove the last tree cause there are NO TREES!'
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For making a whole array lowerCase letters you have to iterate through the trees using `array.map()` and call `toLowerCase()` on each string:

```
const trees = ['oak', 'Pine', 'aspen', 'Bald Cypress']
const lowerCaseTrees = trees.map(tree => tree.toLowerCase())
```

Introduce it into your code by changing `listTrees()` slightly, you want to pass the trees as argument to it for having it dynamic:

```js
var trees = ['oak', 'Pine', 'aspen', 'Bald Cypress']

const errorElement = document.querySelector('#error')
const displayResults = document.querySelector('#displayResults')

const listTrees = () => {
    let treeList = ''
    trees.forEach(tree => {
        treeList += `${tree} <br>`
    })
    
    displayResults.innerHTML = `${treeList} <span>${trees.length} elements long </span>`

}

// show the trees as they are
listTrees()


document.querySelector('#sortTrees').onclick = () => {
    if (trees.length > 0) {
        trees.sort()
        listTrees()
    }
    else {
        errorElement.textContent = 'No Tree'
    }
    
}

document.querySelector('#lowerTrees').onclick = () => {
    if (trees.length > 0) {
        trees = trees.map(tree => tree.toLowerCase())
        listTrees()
    }
    else {
        errorElement.textContent = 'Dude, I cannot remove the last tree cause there are NO TREES!'
    }
    
}
```

```html
<article>
    <button id="sortTrees">Sort the trees A>Z</button>
    <button id="lowerTrees">Make all tress lower case</button>
</article>
<aside>
    <div id="displayResults"> </div>
    <div id="error"></div>
</aside>
```

Here is a handy oneliner (useful for small arrays < 1000 elements)  for making whole tree to `lowerCase()`. This works aslong your trees will not have '##' in its name.

```js
var trees = ['oak', 'Pine', 'aspen', 'Bald Cypress']
var lowerCaseTrees = trees.join('##').toLowerCase().split('##')
console.log(lowerCaseTrees )
```